# Help to show $\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{2^kk!}{\sqrt{(2k+1)!}}=0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Can you help me to show that:

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{2^kk!}{\sqrt{(2k+1)!}}=0$$

Comment: Do you know Stirling's formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [cross-multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-multiplication), for $k\gt0$, we get
$$
\left(\frac{2k}{2k+1}\right)^2\lt\frac{2k}{2k+2}\tag1
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
a_k^4
&=\left(\frac{\color{#C00}{2^kk!}\,\color{#090}{2^kk!}}{\color{#090}{(2k+1)!}}\right)^2\tag2\\
&=\left(\frac{\color{#C00}{2\cdot4\cdots2k}}{\color{#090}{3\cdot5\cdots(2k+1)}}\right)^2\tag3\\
&\lt\frac{2\cdot4\cdots2k}{4\cdot6\cdots(2k+2)}\tag4\\[3pt]
&=\frac1{k+1}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(2)$: expand the terms to the fourth power
$(3)$: keep the red factors in the numerator and cancel the green factors in the denominator
$(4)$: apply $(1)$
$(5)$: cancel the factors in the numerator and denominator

Answer (score 2):

For $k=5$, the square of the general term can be written

$$\frac{2\cdot2\cdot4\cdot4\cdot6\cdot6\cdot8\cdot8\cdot10\cdot10}{2\cdot3\cdot4\cdot5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9\cdot10\cdot11}=
\frac{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdot8\cdot10}{3\cdot5\cdot7\cdot9\cdot11}.$$

Taking the logarithm,

$$\log\frac23+\log\frac45+\log\frac67+\log\frac89+\log\frac{10}{11}<-\frac13-\frac15-\frac17-\frac19-\frac1{11}.$$

Generalizing to the $k^{th}$ term, the logarithm diverges to $-\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

An elementary way using

- $(\star)$: $\prod_{i=1}^k(1+a_i)\geq 1 + \sum_{i=1}^k a_i$ for $a_i \geq 0$ ($i=1,\ldots , k$) and $k \in \mathbb{N}$

$$\frac{2^kk!}{\sqrt{(2k+1)!}}= \frac{2^kk!}{\sqrt{\prod_{i=1}^k 2i \cdot \prod_{i=1}^k (2i+1)}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\prod_{i=1}^k \left(1+\frac{1}{2i} \right)}}$$ 
$$\stackrel{(\star)}{\leq} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^k \frac{1}{i}}}\stackrel{k \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}0$$

Answer (score 1):

By Stirling approximation

$$n! \sim \sqrt{2 \pi n}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$

$$\frac{2^kk!}{\sqrt{(2k+1)!}}=\frac{2^k\sqrt{2 \pi k}\left(\frac{k}{e}\right)^k}{\sqrt[4]{2 \pi (2k+1)}\left(\frac{2k+1}{e}\right)^{k+\frac12}}\sim c\cdot\frac{k^{k+\frac12}}{k^{k+\frac34}}=\frac{c}{k^{\frac14}}\to 0$$